# Unable to pass the env variable to container

Tags: docker, shell, amazon-ecs, datadog

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine

ENV CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1 \
    CORECLR_PROFILER={846F5F1C-F9AE-4B07-969E-05C26BC060D8} \
    CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH=/opt/datadog/Datadog.Trace.ClrProfiler.Native.so \
    DD_INTEGRATIONS=/opt/datadog/integrations.json \
    DD_DOTNET_TRACER_HOME=/opt/datadog

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk --no-cache update \
    && apk add bash make curl

ARG TRACER_VERSION=1.19.1

RUN mkdir -p /opt/datadog
RUN curl -L https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-dotnet/releases/download/v${TRACER_VERSION}/datadog-dotnet-apm-${TRACER_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    |  tar xzf - -C /opt/datadog
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=buildcontainer /app/build .

COPY ./Entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /Entrypoint.sh && /Entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","testdatadog.dll"]
```

Entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 > temp_var
export DD_AGENT_HOST=$(cat temp_var)
exec "$@"
```

When I ssh in to my ec2 and see for environment variables I don't see the DD_AGENT_HOST set. When I am manually trying to set the env it works. Am I missing something? appreciate the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of the problem is that your directive `RUN chmod +x /Entrypoint.sh && /Entrypoint.sh` got executed at BUILD time, and had no impact on your RUNTIME environment.

Konrad's correct in changing your ENTRYPOINT to have Entrypoint.sh change your environment.

The issue with Konrad's solution is that the `run` command he used to start the container had no impact on the bash shell that docker ran when he issued the `exec` command.

Expanding on Konrad's answer a little, you can actually get entrypoint.sh to set your environment for you.

I copied Konrad's Dockerfile, but changed the ENTRYPOINT as follows:

```
FROM alpine:latest AS build

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache bash
COPY --from=build /entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh", "bash" ]
```

Now, the entrypoint.sh will set the environment, and execute `bash`.

I used Konrad's command to run the container:

```
docker run -itd --rm --name entrypoint entrypoint-test:latest
24a7f3d740c37bb345374a835a465482e3bf49a04361e55205b6d63af48d5c3d
```

This results in the container being launched.  Entrypoint.sh will run bash for us, but it's in daemon mode, so we will have to attach to it:

```
$ docker attach 24a7f3d740c37bb345374a835a465482e3bf49a04361e55205b6d63af48d5c3d
bash-5.0# echo $DD_AGENT_HOST 
127.0.0.1
```

Alternatively, you can just run the docker image without the `-d` option, avoiding the daemon mode:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name entrypoint  entrypoint-test:latest
bash-5.0# echo $DD_AGENT_HOST 
127.0.0.1
bash-5.0# echo Hit Ctrl-P Ctrl-Q to leave this container running
```

All that said, will this work for your dotnet invocation?

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh", "dotnet" , "testdatadog.dll" ]
```

Comment: I honestly forgot that Docker has `attach` command. Although I feel it may confuse the OP, since if he uses it with his original image, he won't get dropped to Bash.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
RUN chmod +x /Entrypoint.sh && /Entrypoint.sh
```

actually runs the following command:

```
bash -c "chmod +x /Entrypoint.sh && /Entrypoint.sh"
```

Your script sets the environment variable for the Bash instance that runs it, which itself exits as soon as the script is finished, discarding its environment.

You need to move the execution of `Entrypoint.sh` to the ENTRYPOINT line.

Edit:

So this is my test `Dockerfile` (note that copying and changing permissions on the script is done in a separate stage to reduce the size of the final image):

```
FROM alpine:latest AS build

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache bash
COPY --from=build /entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh", "sleep", "10m" ]
```

and `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
echo "127.0.0.1" > temp_var
export DD_AGENT_HOST=$(cat temp_var)
exec "$@"
```

I ran the following commands:

```
docker build -t entrypoint-test .
docker run -itd --rm --name entrypoint entrypoint-test:latest
docker exec -it entrypoint bash
```

and inside the newly opened Bash shell:

```
export
```

Result:

```
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x HOSTNAME="c951e699bf7b"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
declare -x PWD="/"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
```

No `DD_AGENT_HOST`!

So the I searched for the container's main process (in my case `sleep`)

```
ps -a | grep sleep
```

and got

```
 1 root      0:00 sleep 10m
32 root      0:00 grep sleep
```

Finally I ran

```
strings /proc/1/environ
```

to see the environment of that proces.

Result:

```
HOSTNAME=3f9760ceb473
PWD=/
HOME=/root
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=0
DD_AGENT_HOST=127.0.0.1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

`DD_AGENT_HOST` found!

So what's happening?

It's simple. `entrypoint.sh` sets the variable only for the process it executes - in my case `sleep`. `docker exec` creates a new, unrelated process running Bash. Since a new process (both in Linux and Windows) inherits environment from the parent process and the new Bash process, spawned by `docker exec`, is not a child (but rather a sibling) of the container's main process, it has no knowledge of `DD_AGENT_HOST` variable.

I hope this helps.

Edit 2:

I believe that what [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454209/unable-to-pass-the-env-variable-to-container/63455002#comment112217064_63455002) meant is that you can replace

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh", "sleep", "10m" ]
```

with

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "sleep", "10m" ]
```

and then you can run

```
docker run -it --rm --name entrypoint entrypoint-test:latest bash
```

so that `entrypoint.sh` executes `bash` rather than `sleep 10m`, allowing you to inspect the environment directly rather than through `/proc/$pid/environ`.

The equivalent in your Dockerfile would be:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/Entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "dotnet" , "testdatadog.dll" ]
```

Comment: This doesn't show me the env variable to0 when i do the docker exec on the container instance. COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

Comment: That ENTRYPOINT would cause the container to exit immediately when `entrypoint.sh` finishes executing, which should take so little time I do not see how you could possibly have time to `docker exec` into the container before it stops.

Comment: oh no, I added the dll execution to the sh file.#!/bin/sh

curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 > temp_var
export DD_AGENT_HOST=$(cat temp_var)

if [ ! -z "$@" ]; then
  exec su-exec app "$@"
else
  # Otherwise, run the application
  exec su-exec app dotnet testdatadog.dll
fi

Comment: See my edit for a detailed explanation of where your variable is set.

Comment: You also might clarify that you can change the `ENTRYPOINT` line from the original question to `CMD` in this setup (or for that matter in the original question).  It will get passed as arguments to the entrypoint script, and then `exec "$@"` will run it as the main container process.